# What is the main problem with these queries?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am experiencing slowness issues due to having more than 10 million records in my MySQL table. Please suggest a solution to optimize the performance.

```
$queryCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS counthowmanycompany FROM company_data WHERE RegAddress_County = '$county'";
$query = "SELECT id FROM company_data WHERE RegAddress_County = '$county'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$countHowManyCompany = $result->num_rows;
```

How can I efficiently count the number of rows in my MySQL table? Could you provide a solution? Please rephrase the line accordingly.

Comment: Create an index by `(RegAddress_County)`

Comment: indexing is done.. but still facing a slow issue..

Comment: Your question shows two queries (`$queryCount` and `$query`).  What is performance like with the first query (`$queryCount`)?

Comment: both for similar.. I'm looking for the optimized one so that not to face a slowness issue.

Comment: $query = "SELECT id FROM company_data WHERE RegAddress_County = '$county' AND CompanyStatus = 'active'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $countHowManyCompanyActive = $result->num_rows;   

for example, i tried like this.. as i have more than 1 crore rows in mysql table.

Comment: "what is the main problem with these queries?" Not using PDO or  mysqli prepared statements. Like Akina said use the indexes and how slow is the query? And on what hard ware is your db running

Comment: Run the query directly in the database and see how fast it is. Run an `EXPLAIN` statement on the query to see if it gives you any hints.

Comment: I would expect the `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` query to be faster, as the dataset to be returned is just one row.  If you don't actually need all the `id` values, no need to ask the database server to assemble this large list and send it to PHP.

Comment: How slow is slow? 100ms, 1s, 10s, or more? How many rows match the criteria? Please add the DDL and EXPLAIN output, to your question. The query listed in the comment above has an additional criterion to that listed in your question.

Comment: Please consider posting TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE company_data; for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS counthowmanycompany
    FROM company_data WHERE RegAddress_County = '$county'";
$result = $conn->query($queryCount);
$countHowManyCompany = $result->...   -- get the first column of the first row.
```

You don't need the other query if the only thing you want is the count.

The speed will be proportional to the number of rows in that `RegAddress_County`.